# Is it possible to show function keys on pressing the Command key?

Tags: keyboard, touch-bar

Currently the Touch Bar on my MacBook Pro shows app controls by default and function key when pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. I'd like it to show function keys when pressing the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key as well, because I have Alfred mapped onto <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> for years. I don't want to remap <kbd>⌘</kbd> to <kbd>Fn</kbd> in any way for obvious reasons.

The general reasoning is also simple: you don't press <kbd>⌘</kbd> unless you want to enter a shortcut.

Comment: I think that cmd - <virtual f2> is still hard to press than a combination of real keys. Would you consider to remap?

Comment: @amdyes I've tried to use ⌘2, not only I still press old shortcut, but it conflicts with tab shortcuts in iTerm. I had to resort to showing function keys by default, and it's easy for me to press ⌘F2. One shouldn't underestimate muscular memory.